# Removing 1 NN in a sentence NLTK

Tags: python, nltk, pos-tagger

I want to remove 1 NN in my sentence but my in my code all NN are gone. I just want to remove 1 NN in a sentence thankyou :)

```
text = ' Computes frequency count and fraction of individual words in a list.'
sentence = nltk.word_tokenize(text)
sent = pos_tag(sentence) 
print(text)
rmvnoun = [a for (a,b) in sent if b not in ('NN')]

print(rmvnoun)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! To get help you need to give us enough information to reproduce your problem. Read [mcve] and then [edit] your question.

Answer (score 0):

Using a for loop rather than a list comprehension should make the problem simpler.

```py
rmvnoun = []

for (i, (a, b)) in enumerate(sent):
   if b == 'NN': # or keep it as `b in ('NN')` if you prefer
      break
   rmvnoun += [a]

rmvnoun += [a for (a, _) in sent[i+1:]] # i should be set to the index of the first instance of 'NN' so we add 1 to add all values after that first instance
```